# How to search phone number in google contact without iphone contact sync?

Tags: contacts

I don't want to sync full google contact list but i do want to search some google contact info time to time

How to search google contact phone number without iphone contact sync?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to search for contacts using your mobile browser or Google Apps Directory and Global Address List on iOS, without actually syncing them to your phone.

With your mobile browser:
Go to m.google.com and sign in to your account. You can then go to the contacts and search there.

Or try:

> **How to search your Google Apps Directory and Global Address List on
> iOS**
>
> 1. On your iPhone, launch the Contacts app.
> 2. Go to the Groups selection screen.
> 3. Select *your_account* Global Address List, where *your_account* is what you've named your account on the device.
> 4. Search for a contact.
>
> All of the matching contacts from your directory should show up, such as users in your domain. You can search for users in
> your organization using this method even if they're not listed as
> contacts on your device under **My Contacts**.

From: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/2365056?hl=en